# How to update a GUI component in Qt?

Tags: qt

I am loading a set of 100 images to a `QTableWidget`. Since it takes about 4 seconds loading, I want to show a progress bar (customised one) with activity indicators or spinner etc. How could I update the GUI and the progress bar simultaneously, by signals & slots, and after loading the images?

Comment: What exactly is happening during the "loading"? Are you doing heavy image processing, or just creating `QPixmaps` and throwing them into the table?

Answer (score 0):

Your event loop is busy with your main task, so it can't process your request. All slots will be called after event loop is free. Your options are:

1. Move slow processing to another thread. That may be not an option here because you can't interact with Qt's widgets in non-main thread.
2. Call `QApplication::processEvents()` each time when you want your GUI changes to apply. This is a common and simple solution. This function will execute your slots (if any calls are sheduled), updates GUI and returns execution flow to you.

Answer (score 0):

A better way to load your images would be using a `QThread` that emits a signal as it processes the images, and connect that signal to a slot in your main widget, [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/20497-Showing-progress-bar-while-worker-thread-works) you'll find a couple of examples